# Generic method for checking dependencies related to an entity

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I use the Entity Framework and need to know if an entity has some dependencies that I should make a change of status on an item, but this change can only be performed if there is no dependence that related item. ex:

```
 public class DependencyServices<TEntity> where TEntity: Entity
   {
       public bool VerifyDependencies(TEntity entity)
       {
          if(entity.Dependency != null)
           {
               return true;
           }

           return false;
       }

   }
```

Comment: It is absolutely not clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code only works if Dependency is defined in Entity class. In that case you don't need a generic function, why not define it in Entity class like:

```
public bool HasDependencies
{
   get
   {
      return Dependency !=null;
   }
}
```